# VLC player can't play larger media files on raspbian

Tags: audio, alsa, pulseaudio, vlc

I am using Pi 4 for an week. I tried some media players available on repository like vlc,kodi,mpv etc.
 I have noticed none of them can play a media file(mp4,avi,mkv) smoothly. So I am stuck with vlc. But vlc can't play larger files with audio. Why is this happening?

Comment: I have been using Rpi4B 2GB VLC to play mp3 songs, and so far so good.  I have never played any large files.  Can you give me the link of any large file (must be open, no licence file) so I can download and try to play it?

Comment: Or you might like to read this to see how to get better performance: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/fix-for-vlc-skipping-and-lagging-playing-high-def-video-files/

Comment: I am talking about avi,mkv or mp4 files

Comment: I can play avi files of 900MB large without problem.  But of course it depends on screen size.  I don't have 4k mon.  So I think I can not provide any useful test results for you.  Sorry.

Comment: What do you mean by 'large'? Resolution? Bitrate? File size? Duration? What file types and codecs?

Comment: Is Raspbian Buster fully updated? Try using omxplayer